# Find the derivative of $H(x) = {x^2 +2x +1 \over x^2 -2x +1}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to find the derivative of

$$H(x) = {x^2 +2x +1 \over x^2 -2x +1}$$

I need to follow theorems like,

$$     h(x)= {f(x) \over g(x)}$$
$$h'(x) = {f(x)\cdot  g'(x) - g(x)\cdot f'(x)\over [g(x)]^2}$$

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here's what I did,

$$H'(x) ={(x^2+2x+1)(2x-2) - (x^2-2x+1)(2x+2)\over (x^2-2x+1)^2}$$
Now If keep going like this, would I get right answer??
But I didn't

$$= {(2x^3+4x^2+2x-2x^2-4x-2)-(2x^3-4x^2+2x+2x^2-4x+2)\over(x^2-2x+1)^2}
\\ = {(2x^3+2x^2-2x-2)-(2x^3-2x^2 -2x+2)\over(x^2-2x+1)^2}
\\={ 4x^2-4 \over (x-1)^4}
\\={4(x+1)\over (x-1)^3}$$

It's not right.
it's supposed to be -4. 
What did I do wrong?? I can't find it.

Comment: You should be using $$\frac{f'(x)g(x) - f(x) g'(x)}{(g(x))^2}$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$f(x) = \frac{(x+1)^2}{(x-1)^2} \implies f'(x) = \frac{2(x+1)(x-1)^2 - 2(x-1)(x+1)^2 }{(x-1)^4}$$

Answer (score 2):

It's wrong the rule that you use

$$h'(x)=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{[g(x)]^2}$$

Comment: control! Your formula has the wrong order

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that

Answer (score 2):

you will be better off doing logarithmic differentiation. here is how it works. 
$$H = \frac{(x+1)^2}{(x-1)^2} $$ taking $\ln$  both sides gives you $\ln H = 2 \ln (x + 1) - 2 \ln (x-1).$ differencing this gives you 
$$\frac{dH}H = \frac{2dx}{(x+1)}-\frac{2dx}{(x-1)}$$   rearranging this one gets
 $$\frac{dH}{dx} = \frac{4H}{(x+1)(x-1)}$$